# What is the fastest way to send video frames to a server and then get the data from him?

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc

I am trying to send video from my client to a server and then back to my client!
-> Client to server (video stream)
-> Server to client (answer related to video manipulation)

**What is the fastest way to do it?**
Using a **WebSocket ** connection, I sent the video stream directly to the server, and the server received the frame (did whatever needed to be done to it) and sent it back to the client.

**My results were not fast enough.**
I am not sure if webRTC is what I am looking for because i am not looking to send the data to other clients.

**Client side code:**
Sending frames to server using socket

```
setInterval(() => {
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
      cameraFrame = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
      context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

      socket.emit("frame_data_to_server", { frame: cameraFrame });
      cameraFrame = null;
    }, 1000 / 10);
```

Getting frames from server using socket

```
2. Getting socket events from server
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!socket) {
      console.log("Error establishing socket connection...");
      return;
    }
    socket.on("frame_from_server", (data) => {
      const blob = new Blob([data.image], { type: "image/jpeg" });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      setImage(url);
    });
  }, [socket, img]);
```

Server answer not was quick enough.
Memory leak in client - he is crashing after 1 minute.